# GitHub Page loading Bootstrap CSS, but not my custom stylesheet?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, image, github, github-pages

I am trying to host my website for free using GitHub (and I'm new to GitHub so sorry if this is a dumb question), but it just is not using the stylesheet I created and uploaded with all my files. It also is not loading images from my images folder. So from what I can tell, it doesn't like using local files, but it is fine using linked stylesheets like Bootstrap and images linked from somewhere online.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="_css/bootstrapOverride.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="_css/animate.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

It refuses to use my bootstrapOverride.css and the animate.css.

How can I make it use local files like these? Same question with images as well?

Comment: Any errors on console?

Comment: GET https://brandonstranc.github.io/_css/animate.css 
GET https://brandonstranc.github.io/_js/bootstrapScript.js 
GET https://brandonstranc.github.io/_images/bb.jpg 404 ()
GET https://brandonstranc.github.io/%7B%7Bsite.baseurl%7D%7D_css/bootstrapOverride.css 
GET https://brandonstranc.github.io/_js/bootstrapScript.js

Comment: Can you post your html file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. The issue was my folder names in linking to my stylesheets. GitHub pages uses Jekyll and Jekyll ignores anything after an underscore. Since the folder I had my CSS in was "_css" it would see the underscore and stop there. I took the underscores out of the folder names, updated my links to the CSS and now we are all good!